# Compiling POCO library with MinGW-w64 under Windows (message compiler not found)

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, poco, mingw-w64

I have problems with following part of code from [PocoMacros.cmake](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/cmake/PocoMacros.cmake) file:

```
#  CMAKE_MC_COMPILER - where to find mc.exe
if (WIN32)
  # cmake has CMAKE_RC_COMPILER, but no message compiler
  if ("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Visual Studio")
    # this path is only present for 2008+, but we currently require PATH to
    # be set up anyway
    get_filename_component(sdk_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows;CurrentInstallFolder]" REALPATH)
    get_filename_component(kit_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Kits\\Installed Roots;KitsRoot]" REALPATH)
    get_filename_component(kit81_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Kits\\Installed Roots;KitsRoot81]" REALPATH)
    if (X64)
      set(sdk_bindir "${sdk_dir}/bin/x64")
      set(kit_bindir "${kit_dir}/bin/x64")
      set(kit81_bindir "${kit81_dir}/bin/x64")
    else (X64)
      set(sdk_bindir "${sdk_dir}/bin")
      set(kit_bindir "${kit_dir}/bin/x86")
      set(kit81_bindir "${kit81_dir}/bin/x86")
    endif (X64)
  endif ()
  find_program(CMAKE_MC_COMPILER mc.exe HINTS "${sdk_bindir}" "${kit_bindir}" "${kit81_bindir}"
    DOC "path to message compiler")
  if (NOT CMAKE_MC_COMPILER)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "message compiler not found: required to build")
  endif (NOT CMAKE_MC_COMPILER)
  message(STATUS "Found message compiler: ${CMAKE_MC_COMPILER}")
  mark_as_advanced(CMAKE_MC_COMPILER)
endif(WIN32)
```

So when trying to build library I always got an error:

> message compiler not found: required to build

As you can see since my cmake generator set to "MinGW Makefiles", poco doesn't set path for directories `kit_bindir`, `kit81_bindir` and `sdk_bindir`.

I've tried to set `-Dkit_bindir= "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/bin/x86/"` but build still fails. Also I can't preset CMAKE_MC_COMPILER, since it will be redefined anyway. Official poco tutorial seems useless.

The main question is how to avoid using message compiler by pocolib or how to predefine path to mc.exe? Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

I'm using POCO release v.1.7.6. Version 1.7.7 released still nothing changed. Maybe there some good ports to CMake I could use?

**UPDATE 2** thanks to @sourcedelica

For Poco 1.9.0 you just need to install Windows SDKs and then add C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\x64 to PATH after

Comment: I don't think the poco build system supports mingw-w64. It has a "mingw" entry that is out of date. I had to make a bunch of changes to the build system to make it work. Although this was version 1.6.0, I haven't checked if they have added support since then

Comment: Mine was in a different place: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x64`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution, in PocoMacros.cmake is code:

```
  if ("${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" MATCHES "Visual Studio")
    # this path is only present for 2008+, but we currently require PATH to
    # be set up anyway
    get_filename_component(sdk_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows;CurrentInstallFolder]" REALPATH)
    get_filename_component(kit_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Kits\\Installed Roots;KitsRoot]" REALPATH)
    get_filename_component(kit81_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Kits\\Installed Roots;KitsRoot81]" REALPATH)
    if (X64)
      set(sdk_bindir "${sdk_dir}/bin/x64")
      set(kit_bindir "${kit_dir}/bin/x64")
      set(kit81_bindir "${kit81_dir}/bin/x64")
    else (X64)
      set(sdk_bindir "${sdk_dir}/bin")
      set(kit_bindir "${kit_dir}/bin/x86")
      set(kit81_bindir "${kit81_dir}/bin/x86")
    endif (X64)
  endif ()
  find_program(CMAKE_MC_COMPILER mc.exe HINTS "${sdk_bindir}" "${kit_bindir}" "${kit81_bindir}"
    DOC "path to message compiler")
```

so as you see some necessairy configurations are availabilable only if ${CMAKE_GENERATOR} is "Visual Studio", and unfortunately there is no more Windows Generators available.
As you see necessairy is mc.exe, which is available with Visual Studio, but if you don't have VS (as I don't) you need to download and install [Microsoft SDKs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8279).
Then look to settings:

```
get_filename_component(sdk_dir "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows;CurrentInstallFolder]" REALPATH)
set(sdk_bindir "${sdk_dir}/bin/")
```

you need to copy them just before:

```
  find_program(CMAKE_MC_COMPILER MC.Exe HINTS "${sdk_bindir}" "${kit_bindir}" "${kit81_bindir}"
```

This worked for me and I saw:
"Configuring done
Generating done" in CMake

Comment: For Poco 1.9.0 I just needed to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\x64` to my PATH after installing the Windows SDKs.  No CMakefile changes needed.